# MYSQL - Lock empty rows

Tags: mysql, transactions

How can i lock empty rows?

I want to lock an empty select for example:

## Session 1

```
mysql> begin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from users where username = 'nousername' for update;
Empty set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

## Session 2

```
mysql> begin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from users where username = 'nousername' for update;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I need Session 2 to wait until session 1 is completed before the result is returned.

How can i achieve that?

Thanks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [advisory lock](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock).

Comment: Thanks, that should work. There is no method like FOR UPDATE when you have rows?

Comment: When you actually have rows, `for update` works. When you don't, you would need to lock a predicate instead, and the only means to do so in MySQL that I'm aware of are advisory locks.

Answer (score 2):

There you have three options, each having advantages and disadvantages, I prefer select for update or lock tables:

**1. advisory lock `get_lock()` as mentioned by @Denis:**

cons:

- doesn't get cleared away with commit, rollback,
- system wide names, so you should implement your own unique naming

pros:

- doesn't clear existing transactions
- doesn't block other queries

**2. table lock `lock tables`**

pros:

- does get cleared away with commit, rollback,
- per database locks

cons:

- clears existing transactions

**3. lock tables with pseudo select - Instead of having specific select, i use general select `select max(users_id) from users for update`**

pros:

- does get cleared away with commit, rollback,
- per database locks
- doesn't clear existing transactions

cons:

- doesn't work if table is empty (you need to insert pseudo row, or use dedicated table for locks)